# Systematic way to apply an aggregation function to multiple indexslices in a Pandas hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, multi-index

### Problem

I would like to have a more systematic way to aggregate the frequencies for multiple frequency intervals.

The following dataframe contains random data representing timefrequency data. Its columns index contains the following levels:

1. conditions
2. channels
3. frequencies

The code to generate the dataframe is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pidx = pd.IndexSlice

D=np.zeros((32,2,2,6))# timepoints, conditions, channels, frequencies
for i in range(6):
    D[:,0,0,i]=np.arange(i,i+32,1) # C0, ch01
    D[:,0,1,i]=np.arange(i+1,i+32+1,1) # C0, ch02
    D[:,1,0,i]=np.arange(i+2,i+32+2,1) # C1, ch01
    D[:,1,1,i]=np.arange(i+3,i+32+3,1) # C1, ch02

conditions = ['C0', 'C1']
channels = ["ch{:02}".format(i) for i in np.arange(1,3)]
frequencies = np.arange(1, 7)

# columnns multi index
cidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([conditions,channels,frequencies])
# reshape to 2D
D = D.reshape((D.shape[0], -1))
# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(D, columns=cidx)
```

#### Current solution

Currently I do the following

```py
fbands = {
    'fb1' : [pidx[1:3]],
    'fb2' : [pidx[2:5]],
    'fb3' : [pidx[4:6]]
}
def frequencyband_mean(df, fb):
    return df.loc(axis=1)[:,:,fb].groupby(axis=1,level=[0,1]).mean()

dffbands = dict((k, frequencyband_mean(df, fbands[k])) for k in fbands)
df_result = pd.concat(dffbands, axis=1)
```

However, with the latter code the columnindex levels are not being maintained, more specifically, the first level of `df_result` contains the name of every frequency interval defined in `fbands`. I would solve this by swapping the column levels, but that seems cumbersome.

### Question

I would like to know whether there's a more systematic way to apply an aggregation function to multiple frequency intervals in one go, while maintaining the column index levels. Eventually the last level of the columnindex should look like

1. conditions
2. channels
3. frequency interval names (e.g. `fb1`, `fb2`, `fb3`)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic of `fbands`. Looks like `pidx[1:3]` overlaps with `pidx[2:5]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, it's okay for the frequency intervals to overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correct, then I'd do it like this:

```
fbands={
    'fb1' : [0,3],
    'fb2' : [2,5],
    'fb3' : [4,6]
}

for co_i in df.columns.levels[0]:
    for cha_i in df.columns.levels[1]:
        for k,v in fbands.items():
            df[co_i,cha_i,k] = df[co_i,cha_i,].T[v[0]:v[1]].mean()
```

**Update:** Note that the slice here is not based on the labels, hence you would actually need `v[0]-1:v[1]`; to make this more clear, I'd suggest you simplify your `df`:

```
D=np.zeros((32,2,2,6))
for i in range(6):
    D[:,0,0,i]=np.arange(i,i+32,1) # C0, ch01
    D[:,0,1,i]=np.arange(i+1,i+32+1,1) # C0, ch02
    D[:,1,0,i]=np.arange(i+2,i+32+2,1) # C1, ch01
    D[:,1,1,i]=np.arange(i+3,i+32+3,1) # C1, ch02
```

such that `df.head(3)` returns:

```
    C0                                                          C1                                                        
  ch01                          ch02                          ch01                          ch02                          
     1    2    3    4    5    6    1    2    3    4    5    6    1    2    3    4    5    6    1    2    3    4    5     6
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0   8.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0   9.0
2  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
```

This way, we can actually *verify our expectations*! I am now using `fbands` as an array, rather than a dict, so that the ordering becomes nice (could have also used an `OrderedDict` from `collections`).

```
fbands=[
    ['fb1',[1,3]],
    ['fb2',[2,5]],
    ['fb3',[4,6]]
]
for co_i in df.columns.levels[0]:
    for cha_i in df.columns.levels[1]:
        for fi in range(len(fbands)):
            k=fbands[fi][0]
            v=fbands[fi][1]
            df[co_i,cha_i,k] = df[co_i,cha_i,].T[v[0]-1:v[1]].mean()

for i in range(7):
    df=df.drop(i, axis=1, level=2)

print(df.head(3))
```

returns:

```
    C0                            C1                         
  ch01           ch02           ch01           ch02          
   fb1  fb2  fb3  fb1  fb2  fb3  fb1  fb2  fb3  fb1  fb2  fb3
0  1.0  2.5  4.0  2.0  3.5  5.0  3.0  4.5  6.0  4.0  5.5  7.0
1  2.0  3.5  5.0  3.0  4.5  6.0  4.0  5.5  7.0  5.0  6.5  8.0
2  3.0  4.5  6.0  4.0  5.5  7.0  5.0  6.5  8.0  6.0  7.5  9.0
```

Now, the `fb*` columns actually reflect the mean of frequencies fb1:[1,2,3], fb2:[2,3,4,5] and fb3:[4,5,6], as I *hope you intended*

**Update 2:**
Note that if you would set up your frequencies like this instead:

```
frequencies = ["f{0}".format(i) for i in np.arange(1,7)]
```

then you could e.g. create the means of frequencies `'f1','f2','f3'` in `ch01` within `C0` like this:

```
df['C0','ch01','fb1'] = df.loc(axis=1)[pd.IndexSlice['C0','ch01',['f1','f2','f3'],:]].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: your second update is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are grouping the frequencies in groups of two. If so, try:

```
# it's convenient to groupby over rows than 
data = df.T.reset_index()
data.rename(columns={'level_0':'condition', 
                     'level_1': 'channel',
                     'level_2': 'frequency'},
            inplace=True)

# groupby and compute mean
# review your frequency grouping here
# change mapping frequency -> frequency_band_group
new_df = data.groupby(['condition', 'channel',  (data.frequency-1)//2]).mean()
new_df.drop('frequency', axis=1, inplace=True)

# change name for frequency index
new_df.index.rename('frequency_band', level=2, inplace=True)

# change label for frequency band
new_df.index.set_levels([conditions, channels, ['fb1','fb2','fb3']], inplace=True)

# transform back to get multi-level columns:
new_df.T
```

new_df = data.groupby(['condition', 'channel',  (data.frequency-1)//2]).mean()
new_df.drop('frequency', axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: The frequencies are not being grouped by groups of size 2. The frequency groups are in the example are arbitrary, but should be able to take on any range. specified. Also, `data.groupby(['condition', 'channel',  (data.frequency-1)//2]).mean()` throws `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`, because it's substracting (and dividing) from str types.